# How to retrieve data from mapping table using JPQL without JPA Entity class

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a simple User entity which may have friends (User to User many to many relations) which is mapped in a friends table in database but i don't have a separate Friend entity Object for mapping. Here's the User entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends  Persistent{

@NotEmpty
@Size(min=4,max=16)
@Column(name="USER_NAME",nullable = false,unique = true)
private String username;

@NotEmpty
@Email
@Column(name="EMAIL",nullable = false,unique = true)
private String email;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min=3,max=99)
@Column(name="PASSWORD",nullable = false)
private String password;


@Column(name="ACTIVE")
private boolean active = true;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME",nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="LAST_NAME",nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="DOB",nullable = false)
private String DOB;

@Column(name="PROFILE_PICTURE")
private String profilePicture;

//user activities

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Post> posts;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Comment> comments;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Like> likes;

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="friends",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friendId")})
private List<User> friends;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="friends",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<User> friendsWith;
..... 
}
```

So, I have used eager loading to load friends of User. But say if I want to load friends of User without eagerly loading but using JPQL ... Is it possible to use JPQL to loads User friends info since I don't have a Friend Entity class ?? Do i need to create a separate Friend entity class for mapping freinds ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an association between entities. Associations can be loaded eagerly in JPQL using a fetch join:

```
select distinct u from User u left join fetch u.friends where u.id = :id
```

This applies whatever the association is, and whatever the way it's mapped.

Comment: i want JPQL equilvalent of 
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = :userId)"; 

I am not sure how the above joining helps me .. :/

Comment: What does that have to do with eager loading using JPQL, which is what your question is about? If I understand what your *actual* question is correctly, you want a JPQL query that loads all the friends of a given user, right? The abover query loads the given user with all its friends. So all you need to do is call u.getUser() on the user returned. If you want the friends of the user directly, all you need is `select f from User u join u.friends f where u.id = :id`

Comment: Ok, got it .. thanks .. I was not aware of how the join fetch clause worked ..  :)